# Combining two image label to one label

Tags: image-processing, data-annotations, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging

I have medical images for the prostate where each image has two anatomical labels label0= background label1= peripheral zone, Label2= transitional zone.

I would like to combine two labels so that they become one label and will form the whole prostate structure, Can you help me with this?

attached is the picture to verify my question more:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) the values of your segmentation mask to the range `[0, 1]` (instead of `[0, 2]`): After clipping, all pixels with label > 0 (non-background) will have label 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helped